# Filters Location on Google Map on some attributes in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

In my code doctors are shown on google map , and each doctor have some ettributes
User search by any attributes or couple of attribute, 
If user enter address "USA" and specialization is "Heart" then only those doctors will be shown whose address and specialization is given below

So there are many combination that user can enter
and
I can not understand how to implement these filters,

[image]

My code is

```
  private void showdoctorresult() {
    final String selectedspec = dr_spec_spiner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String selecedgender = gender_spiner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String enteredaddress = mapsearchaddress.getText().toString();
    final String enteredfee = mapsearchfee.getText().toString();
    final String enteredtime = mapsearchtime.getText().toString();

    DatabaseReference doctordRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Doctor");
    mMap.clear();
    doctordRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // SaveDonorData doctordata = dataSnapshot.getValue(SaveDonorData.class);
                String latitude = child.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                String longitude = child.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                String donarname = child.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
                String drspec = child.child("specialization").getValue().toString();
                String draddress = child.child("user_address").getValue().toString();
                String dr_time = child.child("time").getValue().toString();
                String dr_fee = child.child("fee").getValue().toString();
                String dr_gender = child.child("gender").getValue().toString();
                spec.add(drspec);
                double loclatitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                double loclongitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                LatLng cod = new LatLng(loclatitude, loclongitude);

                if(!selectedspec.matches("") || !selecedgender.matches("") || !enteredaddress.matches("") || !enteredfee.matches("")|| !enteredtime.matches("")){
                    if(selectedspec.toLowerCase().contains(drspec.toLowerCase()) && enteredaddress.toLowerCase().contains(draddress.toLowerCase()) && selecedgender.matches(dr_gender) && enteredfee.matches(dr_fee) && enteredtime.matches(dr_time)){
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(donarname));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cod,15));
                    }
                } else
                if(!selectedspec.matches("") || !selecedgender.matches("") || !enteredaddress.matches("") || !enteredfee.matches("") ){
                    if(selectedspec.toLowerCase().contains(drspec.toLowerCase())&& enteredaddress.toLowerCase().contains(draddress.toLowerCase())  && selecedgender.matches(dr_gender) && enteredfee.matches(dr_fee)  ){
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(donarname));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cod,15));
                    }
                }else
                if(!selectedspec.matches("") || !selecedgender.matches("") || !enteredaddress.matches("") ){
                    if(selectedspec.toLowerCase().contains(drspec.toLowerCase()) && selecedgender.matches(dr_gender)&& enteredaddress.toLowerCase().contains(draddress.toLowerCase())     ){
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(donarname));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cod,15));
                    }
                }else
                if(!selectedspec.matches("") || !selecedgender.matches("") ){
                    if(selectedspec.toLowerCase().contains(drspec.toLowerCase()) && selecedgender.matches(dr_gender)   ){
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(donarname));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cod,15));
                    }
                }else
                if(!selectedspec.matches("")  ){
                    if(selectedspec.toLowerCase().contains(drspec.toLowerCase())   ){
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(donarname));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cod,15));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
}
```

How i can make logic to search doctors that user can enter any field and got result
Please Ans me
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

make sql query and fire on firebase storage like below code and you can change according.

```
private void sqlQuery(){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("usersDb").child("UserTable").orderByChild("email").equalTo("vikas@gmail.com");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("Value::",issue.getValue(User.class).email);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but issue is not to get data from fire base

Comment: issue in if else statement

Comment: how i handle user inputs

Comment: if you want to avoid if-else condition then used switch case.

Comment: but how  , i want user inputs in this pictures please see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNutP.png

Comment: the image in show controls is custom define or predefined by google.

Comment: user can enter more then one field then how to handle it

Comment: it is custom defined

Comment: then after you get user input and according to search in database.

Comment: yes i am doing but there is five field that user can entered, if user can enter just 2 fields randomly then how i picked it please see the if else statement

Answer (score 0):

So the first question to answer (and I think you have) would be "Is the user
query an 'AND' or 'OR'" - as in 'I'm looking for all female, heart specialists'
or 'I'm looking for all female doctors or heart specialists'.

So assuming it is an AND the logic for each record is as follows:

```
  onDataChange

     // set flags for each filter based on if any selection made
     set 'specialtySet' to true if selectedSpec not empty string.
     set 'genderSet' to true if selectedGender not empty string.
     // repeat for each filter...

     set lastMarkerLoc = null

     for each child loop

        set 'addMarker' to false

        if 'specialtySet'
           if specialty matches
              set 'addMarker' to true
           else
              // This is the 'AND' all specified filters must pass test.
              // If instead you wanted 'OR' then eliminate the 'continue'
              continue // loop
           endif
        endif

        if 'genderSet'
           if gender matches
              set 'addMarker' to true
           else
              continue // loop
           endif
        endif

        //... repeat similar logic for each filter

        if 'addMarker' is true
           addMarker()
           // no need to move camera for every result
           set 'lastMarkerLoc' to this location

        endif
     endloop

     // zoom camera
     if 'lastMarkerLoc' != null 
        zoom camera to 'lastMarkerLoc'
     endif


  end onDataChange
```

PS - fix typo on 'SEARCH' button.